# Declare two variables split by comma equals to?

Tags: c

`long i, b = get();`

equals to

`long i;
long b = get();`

or

`long b = get();
 long i = b;`

?

I'm totally new to c

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do

Comment: Why do you think `long i = b;` would be there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is first option

```
long i;
long b = get();
```

You would find it out faster by trying then asking on SO.

It's called operator `,`.

In this case both expressions are evaluated, but only second's value is returned.

```
int x = 5;

while (--x, x > 0)
{
    printf("%d,", x);
}
```

has output

```
4,3,2,1,
```

This code is same as

```
--x;
while (x > 0)
{
    printf("%d,", x);
    --x;
}
```

Comment: `long i, b = get();` and "It's called operator ,." --> No. it is not the comma operator anymore than `foo(1,2,3);` or `int a,b,c;` has a common operator.  `x = rand(),1;` has a comma operator.